# How do I permanently convert a template to RTL?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the interface. I have the option to convert the template to rtl, but when refreshing the page, it returns to the default values, which are ltr

this is js:

```
var dzSwitcher = '
<div><p>Direction</p><select class="form-control" name="theme_direction" id="theme_direction"><option value="ltr">LTR</option><option value="rtl">RTL</option></select></div>'



(function($) {
    "use strict"
    addSwitcher();
    const body = $('body');
    const html = $('html');
    const themeDirectionSelect = $('#theme_direction');

    //change the theme direction (rtl, ltr) controller
    themeDirectionSelect.on('change', function() {
        html.attr('dir', this.value);
        html.attr('class', '');
        html.addClass(this.value);
        body.attr('direction', this.value);
    });
```

Comment: You need to persist the LTR text setting somewhere. I'd suggest using localStorage. Then read the setting back when the page next loads and apply it to the UI.

Comment: You're asking how to convert a _template_, but you seem to be asking how to modify a web page. Those are two different things. A template is usually stored on the backend and you'd need to modify it there. Please revise to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have it persist across pages, you will need to use something like localStorage.

I created a function for changing the direction so that it can be used on load as well as on change of the select.

At the end I check for local storage and if it has been saved I use that value to change the direction as well as set your direction select to that value.

```
    const dzSwitcher = '<div><p>Direction</p><select class="form-control" name="theme_direction" id="theme_direction"><option value="ltr">LTR</option><option value="rtl">RTL</option></select></div>'
    
    
    const changeDirection = (direction) => {
      $("html").attr('dir', direction);
      $("html").attr('class', '');
      $("html").addClass(direction);
      $("body").attr('direction', direction);
      localStorage.setItem("direction",direction)
    };

    $("body").append(dzSwitcher)
    
    $(document).on("change", '#theme_direction', function() {
      changeDirection(this.value);
    });
    
    const savedDirection = localStorage.getItem("direction");
    

    if(savedDirection){
        changeDirection(savedDirection)
        $("#theme_direction").val(savedDirection)
    }
```